# URL masking in php?

Tags: php, url, masking

I have a link which is like this:

www.domain.com/index.php?var=string1&var2=string2

I want to mask the url to become something like:

www.domain.com/index.php, or its best to be like this:

www.domain.com

I tried google, I found some methods:

1. Using iframe
2. using frameset
3. Mod_rewrite

I am using php, IIS and mysql, my server is windows server 2003. Which method works best with my server? And how do I mask the URL???

Answer (score 3):

Check the [Microsoft URL Rewrite Module for IIS](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/).